# Method 'value' in COM object of class 'Range' returned error code 0x800A03EC (<unknown>) which means: <unknown>. AX 2012

Tags: excel, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am importing from excel sheet into AX. So the process: Go through records from excel and add them to temp table and populate in grid. This is the process happening. When i use less records ex: 1400 records, its importing into grid without issues. When I am importing 66000 records, it's throwing this above error. Can someone suggest what should i do such that I can import 60000 records at a time?  I tried restarting AX, creating new excel sheet which are suggested online..... Nothing worked.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when develop any import Excel had this problem, when many rows. If there are few rows it works perfect.

For this cases always change the excel import for CSV import. The code to import csv file never fail and work great.

Here I leave an example to import a csv file with 3 rows.

***Code:***

```
static void Stack(Args _args)
{
    AsciiIo               asciiIo;
    container             con;
    FileIoPermission      perm;    
    boolean               _CortarProceso;
    IO_Status             aa;    
    str                   filename;
    str                   _row1, _row2, _row3;            

    Dialog                dialog;
    DialogField           dialogFileName;

    ;

    dialog         = new Dialog("Select CSV File");
    dialogFileName = dialog.addField(ExtendedTypeStr("FilenameOpen"),"Path File:");

    if (dialog.run())
    {
        filename = dialogFileName.value();
    }

    if (!filename)
    {
        return;
    }

    perm = new FileIoPermission(filename, "R");
    perm.assert();
    asciiIo = new AsciiIo(filename, "R");
    asciiIo.inFieldDelimiter(";");

    if (asciiIo != null)
    {
          con = asciiIo.read();
          while((asciiIo.status() == IO_Status::Ok) && (!_CortarProceso)){                          
              _Row1          = conPeek(con, 1); //Row1
              _Row2          = conPeek(con, 2); //Row2
              _Row3          = conPeek(con, 3); //Row3

              if(_row1 != ""){
                  //Your Code...      
                  //Your Code...
                  //Your Code...
                  //Your Code...
                  //Your Code...
              }else{
                  _CortarProceso = true;
              }                        
              con = asciiIo.read();
          }

    }

    info("Process End");
}
```